# How is this piece of code legal java?

Tags: java

I've recently realised you could do this (at least in Java 1.7+).

```
static interface MyInter {
    int foo = 3; 
}
static {
    System.out.println(MyInter.foo);
}
```

How exactly is this legal? 
Does the java compiler just turn `int foo` into a final static field behind the scene or something?

(If that's the case, then, wow, Java is getting crazier and crazier!)

Comment: Where is that `static` block located?

Comment: Well, right below `MyInter` decl, in the same class

Comment: Because that's exactly how fields declared in interfaces work, and have always worked.

Comment: This feature has been with Java since version 1.0. It is only your sentiment about Java which is shifting.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, fields declared in interfaces are implicitly `public`, `static`, and `final`.

[Section 9.3 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.3) states:

> Every field declaration in the body of an interface is implicitly public, static, and final. It is permitted to redundantly specify any or all of these modifiers for such fields.

Answer (score 0):

The specification allows for interfaces to have fields.  All of which are public static final, however these modifiers may be omitted.

> Every field declaration in the body of an interface is implicitly
>   public, static, and final. It is permitted to redundantly specify any
>   or all of these modifiers for such fields.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.3